# Metadata override and base metadata must be of the same type

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, metadata

I'm trying to override the metadata of ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty in a derived class in order to assign my own callback :

```
 public class CustomDataGrid : System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid
 {
    static CustomDataGrid()
    {
        CustomDataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomDataGrid), new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)));
    }

    private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {}
 }
```

I get a designer + runtime exception :

```
Metadata override and base metadata must be of the same type
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to use `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`. All elements that ship with WPF that derive from `FrameworkElement` (and `DataGrid` does) use it as their metadata.

Comment: I'm working with `SnapsToDevicePixesProperty`. If I decompile the code, I see that it's initially registered with plain old `PropertyMetadata`. However, if I inspect it in the debugger at runtime, I see two entries in its `_metadataMap`--a `PropertyMetadata` and a `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`. Apparently the framework adds an additional owner somewhere? Does this imply the rule is that, when adding a property owner, your metadata type must match or derive from the *most derived type* already registered?

Comment: I think that would be a safe assumption. Otherwise, the class that registered the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` would have an exception when trying to access its metadata